# How to prevent patterns from touching the edges of the selection?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns, fill

[image]

I created a pattern to fill into the selection as shown above, but I dont want the star patterns to touch the edges as I have to give it for laser cutting. Is there any way we could solve this issue?

Comment: Whats worng with expanding and deleting the sampes you dont want.

Answer (score 1):

There is a couples of simple solutions

1. you can use appearance so your border have a sounding white space that cover the starts when it appear underneath, or
2. you can draw a white rectangle that contain your pattern in a separated layer and the border in another layer that inner padding that is far from the white rectangle the distance you want.